# Erro no sqlite e javascipt

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

Eu estava fazendo uma video aula e segui os exatos mesmos passos do professor, porém esta dando o seguinte erro quando executo o codigo no powershell

Ate antes de começar a introduzir o sqlite tava rodando normal

"(node:4224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: sqlite: filename is not defined
...
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:10724) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code."

```
const express = require('express') /* para importar o express */
const app = express()

const sqlite = require('sqlite')

let db = new sqlite.Database(':memory:', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the in-memory SQlite database.');
  });
const dbConnection = sqlite.open('banco.sqlite', { Promise })

app.set('view engine', 'ejs') //seta parametros para olhar na pasta view, e procurar arquivos .ejs
app.use(express.static('public')) 

/*apos verificar um pedido (chamar o /) na porta 3000 o app pega com o .get o request 
e responde o response enviando a mensagem  */

app.get('/', (request, response) => {     /* pega as insformações do app */
   
    response.render('home' )     // renderiza o arquivo home.ejs
    
})
app.get('/vaga', (request, response) => {     
        response.render('vaga')
 
})

const init = async () => {   
    const db = await dbConnection 
    await db.run('create table if not exists categorias (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, categoria TEXT') 
}

init()

/* o app fica escutando a porta 3000 */
app.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log('Não foi possivel inciar o servidor do Jobify.')
    }else{
        console.log('Servidor rodando...')
    }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Olá,

Encontrei a solução num fórum do [github](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/issues/302)

Fazendo downgrade pra versão do professor (3.0.0), provavelmente vá funcionar o código. Coloca no terminal:

yarn add sqlite@^3.0.0

A versão >4 do Sqlite requer alguns parâmetros diferentes pra abrir o DB, por isso não está batendo com o que você está tentando.

Answer (score -2):

Tive alguns problemas com Sqlite tambem , uma solução que fiz foi fazer o downgrade do Node para mesma versão das aulas que estava tendo , mas um tempo depois apos inserir algumas dependencias houve o mesmo erro , então resolvi , desistalar o Node e usar a versão Current  , e fazer a instalação um a um das dependencias que estava usando para atualizar o package.json , e com isso funcionou ( ate o momento ) sei que para colocar o projeto em produção não é ideal a versão do Node Current , pois pode haver algumas falhas , mas por outro lado nele há atualizações maiores que a versão LTS  , então verifique sua versão de Node , faça os testes com a versão Current